# How to consume REST API key in my android app?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application which consumes a public REST API, in which I have been provided with a developer key. How should I implement the key in my application ?
Will every application in different devices have my same developer key embedded into them? And if so, I only have a limited quota for the developer key, How should I manage it?
Or How to have different unique API keys for each app on different devices so that each application has their own quota and how should I manage it?

For example - Scenario 1(Question 1) - Suppose the Developer quota = 1000 hits, and application runs on 5 different devices then, on accessing and retrieving the info from the API would deplete my developer quota very fast.

Scenario 2(Question 2) - On not using the developer key(quota) , here each application on each devices have their individual quota = 1000 hits. Simply like each device having their own account.

I'm new to REST APIs and thought about the scenarios above but I don't know how to implement and manage them or what is the actual correct solution of Implementing a REST API key in my application?

I have already successfully tested my application on my device using my developer key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the quota management, it's the backend logic and it handles user requests so you should follow the backend way in scenario 1. Here is how it should work.

1. Device Login. On success, the server returns an `access token` as a response. Store token in device safe place(i.e. `SharedPreferences` in android).
2. Send the token in `Authorization` header of every request to the server, Your server should be guarded by `Authorization`. Server updates the quota consumed for the day. Here is how the server can manage quota,

   ‣ Identify user based on the token in `Authorization` header and update the quota.
   ‣ If quota exceeds, return some meaningful error to the device.

For scenario 2, make the token `User Independent` (multiple device logins allowed for the same account). By making the token `User Independent` and above given flow, you can achieve aspects given in your question. let me know if you have a question.

I suggest using `JWT Token`. as it's a standard JSON web token and globally used. it has several benefits and availability on major platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, that means it completely relies on backend logic, Do you have any references which would help me design my above scenarios on the backend servers, basically a how to guide or examples.

Comment: Here is a post about how to implement in Node.js, as I don't know what technologies you are using in the backend, I'm referring https://medium.com/dev-bits/a-guide-for-adding-jwt-token-based-authentication-to-your-single-page-nodejs-applications-c403f7cf04f4

Comment: Here access token itself contains info about the user whom the token belongs and token should be signed by your `private key` stored on the server. So, you can confirm the token is issued by your server by verifying the `signature`. By decoding the `jwt-token` you will get everything you have stored in that token on login time. You should also visit http://jwt.io

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the API key either in headers of the API or in the parameters.
For example if you are using Retrofit the implementing key in headers will look like this :

```
@Headers({"key: your_key"})
@POST("user/classes")
Call<playlist> addToUserlist(@Body UserParam parm);
```

Or if you want to implement it in parameters it will look like this :

```
@POST("user/{key}/classes")
Call<playlist> addToUserlist(@Path("key") String your_key);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am already past this stage as I have already tested my application on my device, to rephrase my question, how should I implement the key logic in my application for release version as stated in the question?